# Why Are The Headers From my Frontend Not Making it To Node Backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a simple API call that sends two headers from the React frontend to the Node backend. I haven't been able to figure out why the headers aren't making it to the backend. My POST function looks exactly like my other functions that are successfully passing headers.

React method to make the call:

```
const setHabitAsComplete = async (habitId) =>{
    const date = getCurrentDate()
    const user_id = localStorage.getItem('user')
    console.log(user_id, date). //values here are correct
    await api.post(`/habit/mark_complete/${habitId}`, {headers: { user_id, date }})
  }
```

Node method consuming the call:

```
 async markComplete(req, res){
    
    const { user_id, date } = req.headers
    const { habitId  } = req.params

   try {
    console.log(user_id, date) //returns undefined 
    console.log(habitId) //returns correct value from the params
   } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Unable to mark habit as complete!'})
   }    
  }
```

When I send the request from Insomnia (API testing tool) and manually set the headers the Node method is able to receive and log them correctly, so my suspicion is something is wrong with the React method.

Comment: What does the browser's network tab tell you?

Comment: I'm not seeing any headers in the network tab :/

Comment: I think you should find out whether it is a sending problem or receiving problem. You can first check the XHR to find out if those 2 values are really included in the Request Header. If not, there is a sending problem. If yes, check if node received other values, like Host, User Agent, in headers other than user_id and date. If yes, then it is a receiving problem. You need to check through the pipeline of node server to find out where the value is missing.